# why doesn't this month representation work?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

```
 return pd.Period(today().year, 'Y')
```

today() is a datetime object and this represents a year period. However, it fails when I want to represent a month in a similar way:

```
return pd.Period(today().month, 'M')
```

This gives an error:

```
ValueError,  Given date string not likely a datetime .
```

Why is that?

Comment: Can you include `type(today())`?

Comment: @RichieV, datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 25, 21, 11, 25, 937161)

Comment: why is probably because there is a parser that infers the type, so it has to handle all kinds of different cases.  In this case, they're guessing you've made an error

Comment: You can just use `return pd.Period(today(), "M")` however - that should give you what you want.

Comment: Try withouth the month attribute... `pd.Period(today(), 'M')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `pandas.Period` instance represents a specific time period. A month period is a specific month, like January 2016, not just "one month".

When you call `pd.Period(today().month, 'M')`, you're not providing enough information for Pandas to determine which month the Period is supposed to represent.